# How do you fix the missing templates error in rails despite the save function working?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to send messages, and then have them appear in a chatbox. Every time I send a message, it leads to the error below. If I refresh the page and open the chatbox, it contains the message I last entered (meaning save! is working). Is there a special usage of the "path" variable that can fix this?

> Error: Missing template messages/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :rabl, :jbuilder]}

Messages Controller (relevant function)

```
  def create
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
    @message = @conversation.messages.build(message_params)
    @message.user_id = current_user.id
    @message.save!
    @path = conversation_path(@conversation)   
  end
```

Conversations Controller (relevant functions)

```
  def create
    if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id]).present?
      @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id]).first
    else
      @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
    end

    render json: { conversation_id: @conversation.id }
  end

  def show
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])
    @reciever = interlocutor(@conversation)
    @messages = @conversation.messages
    @message = Message.new
  end
```

_message.html.erb

```
<li class="<%=  self_or_other(message) %>">
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
  </div>
  <div class="chatboxmessagecontent">
    <p><%= message.body %></p>
    <time datetime="<%= message.created_at %>" title="<%= message.created_at.strftime("%d %b  %Y at %I:%M%p") %>">
      <%= message_interlocutor(message).uname %> • <%= message.created_at.strftime("%H:%M %p") %>
    </time>
  </div>
</li>
```

create.js.erb (within the messages folder along with _message)

```
<% publish_to @path do %>
    var id = "<%= @conversation.id %>";
    var chatbox = $("#chatbox_" + id + " .chatboxcontent");
    var sender_id = "<%= @message.user.id %>";
    var reciever_id = $('meta[name=user-id]').attr("content");

    chatbox.append("<%= j render( partial: @message ) %>");
    chatbox.scrollTop(chatbox[0].scrollHeight);

    if(sender_id != reciever_id){
        chatBox.chatWith(id);
        chatbox.children().last().removeClass("self").addClass("other");        
        chatbox.scrollTop(chatbox[0].scrollHeight);
        chatBox.notify();
    }
<% end %>
```

Conversations/show.html.erb

```
<div class="chatboxhead">
  <div class="chatboxtitle">
    <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>

    <h1><%= @reciever.uname %> </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="chatboxoptions">
    <%= link_to "<i class='fa  fa-minus'></i> ".html_safe, "#", class: "toggleChatBox", "data-cid" => @conversation.id %>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <%= link_to "<i class='fa  fa-times'></i> ".html_safe, "#", class: "closeChat", "data-cid" => @conversation.id %>
  </div>
  <br clear="all"/>
</div>
<div class="chatboxcontent">
  <% if @messages.any? %>
      <%= render @messages %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="chatboxinput">
  <%= form_for([@conversation, @message], :remote => true, :html => {id: "conversation_form_#{@conversation.id}"}) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_area :body, class: "chatboxtextarea", "data-cid" => @conversation.id %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= subscribe_to conversation_path(@conversation) %>
```

application.js

```
// These plugins must be loaded first

//= require plugins/jquery
//= require jquery.iframe-transport
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require plugins/picker
//= require jquery_ujs
// Extra

//= require_directory ./plugins
//= require_directory ./components

//= require common
//= require user_info_boxes
//= require moment
//= require fullcalendar
//= require underscore
//= require introjs

//Required For Chats
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require private_pub
//= require chat
//= require users
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where's your form for the message? Does it have `remote: true` on?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Added.It is in conversations/show.html. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Messages Controller, have you tried:

```
def create
  @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  @message = @conversation.messages.build(message_params)
  @message.user_id = current_user.id
  @message.save!
  redirect_to @conversation
end
```

Comment: Tried this, but it leads me to a new page with a list of all the messages, instead of having the message show up in the chatbox.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you jquery_ujs is getting loaded properly.

Or else try with //= require_tree . once in your application.js

Comment: I tried require_tree but that did not fix the problem. How do I know if jquery_ujs is getting loaded properly?